# Change values in argument array in pybind11

Tags: python, numpy, eigen, pybind11

I have the following small `pybind11` code:

```
void f(
    Eigen::MatrixXd& vertices
){
    vertices(0, 0) = 55.0;
}

PYBIND11_MODULE(test, m) {
    m.def("f", &f, "");
}
```

And the corresponding Python:

```
v = np.array([[1, 2], [1, 2]])
f(v)
print(v)
```

So basically, I create a Numpy array, and the Python bindings are supposed to write 55 into one of the array cells.

Unfortunately, when printing `v`, it seems that 55 was not written into it.

**How can I achieve that the changes to the array in the C++ code also take effect in the Python code?**